# MySQL Trigger: Can I use Update?

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER history BEFORE UPDATE ON bestbuy

 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 IF NEW.salePrice <> OLD.salePrice THEN

 INSERT INTO history_price (modelNumber,salePrice)
        VALUES (OLD.modelNumber,OLD.salePrice);

        ELSEIF NEW.salePrice = OLD.salePrice THEN
            SET NEW.salePrice = OLD.salePrice;

    END IF;

 END
```

My question:
is it valid to use

CREATE TRIGGER history BEFORE **REPLACE** ON bestbuy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not - valid events are only *INSERT*, *UPDATE* and *DELETE*.

Are you sure you are updating data with `REPLACE`? - you could change that, to update it with `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` - so your trigger will run

**Edit** to address the comments

take a look at [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://INSERT%20...%20ON%20DUPLICATE%20KEY%20UPDATE%20Syntax) on the MySQL site - it's an ordinary INSERT, with a clause in it - I also think its a better performer than `REPLACE`, because this does not delete the record to insert it again, it just updates the values

Comment: I'm using this statement to load data:LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE
'c:/users/ryan/desktop/BBY_PRICES_FULL.xml'
REPLACE INTO table bestbuy
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>'. Do you know if there is  way to get around this?

Comment: yes, change `REPLACE INTO table bestbuy ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>'` with `INSERT INTO bestbuy (fields) VALUES (values) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1=val1, field2 = val2, etc`

Comment: For values, would they be the XML tags like VALUES ('<modelNumber>')?

Comment: Now, I need to figure out how to use the data from the XML file